# Android Google Analytics Exception logging

Tags: android, exception, google-analytics

I'm using [Google Analytics SDK v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions) for Android to record the exceptions. I followed the sample app but I could see no exceptions getting registered in the dashboard.

I wrote the code as below

```
/*exception tracking */
// Get tracker.
Tracker t2 =
  ((MyApp) this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

// Build and send exception.
int a = 0;
String exceptionStr = "";

try{
  int b = a/0;
}catch(Exception ex){
  exceptionStr = ex.toString();
}finally{
  t2.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
          .setDescription(exceptionStr + ":" + "In Main screen")
          .setFatal(true)
          .build());

  GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).dispatchLocalHits();

  Log.v("Manual logging", "finished for analytics");
}
```

`"Manual logging", "finished for analytics"` is showing up in the logcat window but when I check the analytics there is nothing registered.

BTW the user screen flow etc working just fine with the SDK. Just the exception logging is not working.

Comment: Google analytics takes upto 24 hrs to reflect the updates in dashboard.If you want to view the current changes than you need to use Real time functionality inside Goolge Analytics.

Comment: You are correct now it's showing up the exceptions :)

Comment: This was helpful -- but needs an official answer. I put one up but if @Siddharth_Vyas wants to make his official I will vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

Data can take some time to show up in the GoogleAnalytics dashboard. Give it some time, it will show up under exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me but I'm using [advanced crash report implementation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions#exception-reporter).

Go to Behavior --> Crashes & Exceptions

In the top right drop-down (below date range selector), select **"Faster Response, less Precision"** option instead of the default **"Slower Response, Greater Precision"**:

[image: Faster Response, less Precision]

Also, additionally, you can click on the **"Refresh Report"** button in the lower right corner if the last reported generated is stale:

[image: "Refresh Report"]

If none of the above work, then wait for 24 hours for GA to generate the reports :)